# Bourbon Neat, how to make a fixed positioned element work with grid system?

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

How do I make a fixed positioned element work with Neat grid system? box3 is an element with fixed position, I didn't give it a width because I want it to fit in the grid with `span-columns(6)` and `shift(3)`, so it is centered. Anyway can make this happen? Any help would be appreciated.

```
.test {
  @include outer-container;
  @include padding(15px);
  border: 1px solid red;
.box1 {
  @include span-columns(6); 
  border: 1px dashed green;
  height: 100px;
 }
.box2 {
   @include span-columns(6);
   @include omega;
   border: 1px dashed green;
height: 100px;
}
.box3 {
  @include span-columns
  background:red;
  opacity:.5;
  @include position(fixed);
  padding:30px;
  color:white;
}
```

[Live code is here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/4cfb8e64d951a8b473da)

Answer (score 0):

Your live code does not reflect what you have above.

As for the fixed positioning breaking the grid, fixed positioning is always relative to the window, not an element.

To fix, put a wrap inside of your ".box3" class, position that fixed, and give "box3" a height.

Comment: "Your live code does not reflect what you have above" -probably because this question was asked 7 months ago. :)

Comment: doesn't mean it still isn't relevant, I found it because I had the same issue :) Bourbon doesn't handle fixed elements in columns very well.